# Visual Studio Deployment Project for x86 and x64 installers

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 32bit-64bit

I have a Visual Studio 2010 Deployment Project and I now have the need to have an x64 installer for our product. I have various custom bootstrappers which check to see if the system is x86 or x64. The only change I think I need to make prior to building is setting the TargetPlatform to x64 on the Deployment Project properties panel, and changing the File System's Program Files special fodler to be [ProgramFiles64Folder].

I can't figure out how I can change the Configuration Manger to retain these changes between x86 and x64. An installer project can't seem to have an an Platform associated with it. Even creating a seperate Configuration for x64 (which is what the Platform SHOULD be for), this doesn't save the x86/x64 decision, but would only let me save different prerequisites behind a Configuration.

Is there an easy way I can switch between x64 and x86 on my installer? I'd prefer not to have to change the Program Files folder and platform on the installer project properties every time I want to build, nor do I want to make a copy of the installer project and keep it x64 only, as that would be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: No.  Just create two Setup projects.

Comment: ok, how can i close this question if there is no "answers". Want to add this as an answer? your comment is actually answering the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Just create two Setup projects. –  Hans Passant